# Doesn't work on tcsh: set kk=`cd $THE_PATH; pwd`

Tags: bash, csh, tcsh

A typical way to get the absolute path in BASH is:

```
`cd $THE_PATH; pwd`
```

But this doesn't work on tcsh/csh. if in tcsh, you

```
set kk=`cd $HOME; pwd`
```

the kk will hold the correct value of the absolute path, however, very weird, "ls $kk" gives you error, it says the path doesn't exist~!!

Can anyone inform me why this happened? Thanks.

[EDIT]

```
set kk=`cd $HOME; pwd`
cd $kk
```

will give this:

```
"^[]2;myid@machine003:/u/myid^G: No such file or directory."
```

But echo $kk is fine~

```
"/u/myid"
```

Comment: What is the output of `echo $kk` and what value did you expect?

Comment: It works find for me, at least for a couple of cases I just tried.  What is the value of `$THE_PATH`, what directory are you starting in, and what is the value of `$kk` after you set it?  Spaces or other special characters in your path could explain the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Try doing this: `echo "$kk" > temp.txt` and then see what `temp.txt` contains. I wonder if you're picking up characters (such as Ctrl-G) that don't echo out, but are still part of the string. I tried your examples, but they work with tcsh on my system.

Comment: @David. Yes, just like what I edited in the question, `echo "$kk" > temp.txt` shows that it contains weird characters. I just don't understand why this happened. "cd" is shell built-in, and pwd is /bin/pwd.

Comment: @solotim: Can you show us the `cwdcmd` alias? Please enter `alias cwdcmd`.

Comment: @bmk: # alias cwdcmd
echo "\e]2;$USER@${HOST}:$cwd\a\c"
 Note that this alias doesn't exist in my BASH shell.

Comment: @solotim: Could you try to execute the commands of your question after doing `unalias cwdcmd`?

Comment: @bmk: Thanks, it works now. So the solution is unalias cwdcmd? Is there any side effect by doing so?

Comment: @solotim: I will put this into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you defined a `cwdcmd` alias. Regarding the `tcsh` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) the `cwdcmd`

```
... Runs after every change of working directory. ...
```

I.e.: When you execute `cd` the defined `echo` command is also executed and the output is saved into the `$kk` variable.

To avoid this you can delete the `cwdcmd` alias:

```
unalias cwdcmd
```

But be aware that that has the side effect that the desired functionality (probably setting the `xterm` title) does not work anymore then.